# How to query the music library of a mobile device (both iOS and Android) using the Qt framework?

Tags: android, ios, qt, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying to build yet another specialized music player which should run seamlessly both on Android and iOS (and of course on the more common desktop platforms such as Linux and MacOs and possibly Windows). The Qt framework seems to be the best option so I am currently using Qt 5.11.1 and began by cannibalizing their "Multimedia Player" example.

However, what I now need to do is to query and autoload the music library residing locally in the mobile device, and I need to do it reliably and portably across platforms. I cannot see any way to do this with Qt, and I am stuck with this problem; and by the way, the QStandardPaths class from Qt 5 seems to be completely broken as far as music is concerned: it reports reliably the music location path only for the MacOs desktop platform - Linux, Android and iOS are not reported correctly.

Is there any way to do this correctly? Please advise, thank you.

Comment: The respective owners of music API-s of those platforms put extra effort into making those as different as possible so correct way is to write platform-specific code for each case.

Comment: Thank you @ÖöTiib for your comment but then what's so good about using Qt? Every API for any function is as different as possible, so why music should require native code?

Comment: Qt is not portable framework of everything. It is mainly portable GUI framework. It contains lot of other portable code not directly related to GUI but portable interface to music APIs is not one of those things.